How can export a CSV with Shift-Jis encoding in Google Apps Script?
I want export  a CSV with Shift-Jis encoding  in Google Apps Script.
This is my code:
function exportToCSV() {
  var csvContent = '歳以上,三井ﾎｰﾑｺﾝﾎﾟｰﾈﾝﾄ㈱･横浜 -- HLⅢ 片流れ･ｼﾞｮｲﾝﾄ水切り250 2個入 B'; 
  var shiftJisBlob = Utilities.newBlob(csvContent, 'text/csv').setDataFromString(csvContent, 'Shift_JIS');
  shiftJisBlob.setName('data_shiftjis.csv');
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(shiftJisBlob);
  Logger.log('File CSV : ' + file.getUrl());
}

This is Result opening by Notepad++: It can create CSV with Shift-Jis encoding, but some character is not correct.

How can export a CSV with Shift-Jis encoding  in Google Apps Script?

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following answer?
When I saw your text 歳以上,三井ﾎｰﾑｺﾝﾎﾟｰﾈﾝﾄ㈱･横浜 -- HLⅢ 片流れ･ｼﾞｮｲﾝﾄ水切り250 2個入 B and your showing image, it seems that the extended characters like ㈱ and Ⅲ. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue. In this case, how about using CP932 instead of Shift-JIS? When this is reflected in your script, please modify it as follows.
From:
var csvContent = '歳以上,三井ﾎｰﾑｺﾝﾎﾟｰﾈﾝﾄ㈱･横浜 -- HLⅢ 片流れ･ｼﾞｮｲﾝﾄ水切り250 2個入 B'; 
var shiftJisBlob = Utilities.newBlob(csvContent, 'text/csv').setDataFromString(csvContent, 'Shift_JIS');

To:
var csvContent = '歳以上,三井ﾎｰﾑｺﾝﾎﾟｰﾈﾝﾄ㈱･横浜 -- HLⅢ 片流れ･ｼﾞｮｲﾝﾄ水切り250 2個入 B';
var shiftJisBlob = Utilities.newBlob("", 'text/csv').setDataFromString(csvContent, 'CP932');


I guess that in this case, CP932, Windows-31J and MS932 show the same results.

